# How to send a file to Restify API and save it in MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, restify

For a school project i needed to upload a file to a mariadb table via drag&drop.
I am currently using node.js and restify for the back-end, and jquery for the front-end. I just cant manage to make it work.
Here is how i send the file:

`<div id="drop">Drop the file</div>
 <div id="status1"></div>
 <button id="send" >send</button>`

```
$(function () {

var dropzone = $("#drop");
var sendFile;

$("#send").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "172.16.3.146:8000/subir",
        type: 'POST',
        data :{file:sendFile},
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data,error){
            alert(data+" "+error);
        },
        error: function(data,error){
            alert("something happened "+data+" "+error);
        }
    });
});

 dropzone.on('drop', function (e) {
    console.log("droped");
    $(this).css('border', '2px dotted #0B85A1');
    e.preventDefault();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

    handleFileUpload(files);

});

function handleFileUpload(files) {   
    sendFile = new FormData();        
    sendFile.append('file', files[0]); 
    $('#status1').html("file--->" + files[0].name + " --> " + files[0].size + " KB");                
     
    console.log("uploaded " + files[0].name + files[0].size);
}
```

For the back-end I already saw that restify does not support multipart form-data and read a little of the require library but really didn't understand the concept and managed to make it work.
Here is my app:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'servilleta',
    password: 'guest',
    database: 'guest'
});

var ip_addr = '172.16.3.146';
var port = '8000';
var http = require('http');
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'apirest'
});

server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(restify.CORS());
server.listen(port, ip_addr, function () {
    console.log('%s active on %s ', server.name, server.url);
});

function uploadFile(req, res, next) {
console.log("A file wants to be uploaded");
var query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + req.params.file + "'INTO TABLE Practica11 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (nombre,ApellidoPat,ApellidoMat,NumeroCuenta,Carrera) ";
connection.query(query, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(200, result);
    return next();
    });
}
request.post({
    path: '/subir/',
    formData: formData
}, uploadFile);

connection.end();
```

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Not sure what question is?

Comment: if there is an error either on browser console or on nodejs side, please post it too